# What are Apocalypse's original mutant powers, and what abilities did he gain from the Celestial technology?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I was always a bit uncertain of the difference between the two. I checked around, and got some good ideas, but nothing concrete. Most followed the format (or at least, maintained the same level of general discourse) of this video:

Same problem arises; speaks to *all* of his powers, but not *directly* separating what he was born with, and what he gained via the alien tech.

Complicating matters is that Apocalypse can apparently *retain the powers of mutant bodies he has inhabited before,* making his *original* abilities even murkier.

Can anyone please **clarify this?** Specifically, we should look at:

- What are ALL of Apocalypse's powers
- What powers he has **as a mutant,** i.e. his *original* abilities
- What powers he got from **the Celestial technology** and *how* those affected/augmented his *natural* abilities.
- What powers he retains **from other mutants**
- To **what degree** his powers are amplified due to this blending.

Canonical sources may be best, but considering there are a number of sources in various media, and different versions, if evidence is provided, it can be pulled from all of them.

Comment: Useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBsSMpkXPHg&t=454s

Answer (score 2):

I believe his only true mutant power was the ability to alter his molecular make-up.
This effectively gave him access to many different kinds of power. Shapeshifting, fast healing, more strength, and many others.
The rest really depends on which storyline you choose. His powers and origins of those powers vary with each one.

Comment: Nice answer. However, can you add some sources that support your answer ?